# PHP Mysqli Reading Array of Objects from Database converting to JSON

Tags: php, json, object, mysqli, stdclass

```
$query = "SELECT guid, name, location, description, datetime FROM event";

   $result = doSQLTermError($db_connect, $query);

   while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
      $guid = $obj->guid;

      $event_details = new stdClass;

      $event_details->$guid = new stdClass;
          $event_details->$guid->name = $obj->name;
          $event_details->$guid->location = $obj->location;
          $event_details->$guid->description = $obj->description;
          $event_details->$guid->datetime = $obj->datetime;   
   }

   $event = json_encode($event_details);
```

The code above gives me following desired JSON output:

```
"data":
{
   "f4ef863ef80b07036de08457ccdf51e3f814":
    {
       "name":"adsg",
       "location":"uhjty;",
       "description":"y;hy",
       "datetime":"2018-01-01 00:00:00"
    }
}
```

However it only reads the last event record from the database. How can I list all of the events in the database but keep the above JSON format? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `$event_details = new stdClass;` out of the while loop.
You are overwriting the `$event_details` variable with a new instance every time so you loose the data which is already in it from the previous loop.

Answer (score 0):

You must use array to get all data from SQL query:

```
$query = "SELECT guid, name, location, description, datetime FROM event";

$result = doSQLTermError($db_connect, $query);
$events = [];

while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
     $guid = $obj->guid;
     $event_details = new stdClass;
     $event_details->$guid = new stdClass;
     $event_details->$guid->name = $obj->name;
     $event_details->$guid->location = $obj->location;
     $event_details->$guid->description = $obj->description;
     $event_details->$guid->datetime = $obj->datetime;
     $events[] = json_encode($event_details);
}
```

Comment: You are creating an array of strings which is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @jeroen then must be `$events[] = $event_details;`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $query = "SELECT guid, name, location, description, datetime FROM event";

   $result = doSQLTermError($db_connect, $query);

   $event_details = new stdClass;

   while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
      $guid = $obj->guid;

      $event_details->$guid = new stdClass;
          $event_details->$guid->name = $obj->name;
          $event_details->$guid->location = $obj->location;
          $event_details->$guid->description = $obj->description;
          $event_details->$guid->datetime = $obj->datetime;   
   }

   $event = json_encode($event_details);
```

Comment: Maybe explain your answer

Comment: @Lokuzt Which part of the answer, do you need further explanation on ?